# SqlDataReader returns empty

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;" + "Initial Catalog=OnlineBanking");
            _sqlConnection.Open();
            var cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("Select * from BankAccounts where AccountId = 1", _sqlConnection);
            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    dataReader.Read();
                    float AccountBalance = (float)dataReader["Balance"];
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", AccountBalance);
                }
            }
```

This line

```
 float AccountBalance = (float)dataReader["Balance"];
```

causes problems, as dataReader returns empty. How can I fix it? What's the issue?

Comment: What do you mean with _datareader returns empty_ ? Do you have an exception with a meaningfull error message?

Comment: When run in SSMS, what gets returned? Please post data results that you think you should get.

Comment: You are using SqlConnection incorrectly. It implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). You need to wrap it in a using statement.

Comment: @Steve, I mean that in the debugging mode I can see: dataReader->Results View -> Empty.
The exception I get is "System.InvalidCastException "

Comment: What is the datatype of the field "Balance" on the database table. You are casting it to a float but it tells you that this is not possible.

Comment: And what happens when you step through the code line by line?

Comment: @WEI_DBA in SSMS it returns a row with the AccountId being 1 and balance being some number. The Balance column is set to float in the database.

Comment: @Steve [Balance]    FLOAT (53) DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,

Comment: sql float is mapped to net double https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings but as explained below by Marc use a decimal type to store and handle monetary values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.InvalidCastException` (comments) is not "empty" - it is an invalid cast. So presumably the data **isn't a `float`**; it could be `double`, or - and I suspect this is the case: `decimal`. Note that `decimal` is a **much** better choice for numbers that represent money.

So: find out which it is, and use the correct cast. I suspect that this will work:

```
decimal accountBalance = (decimal)dataReader["Balance"];
Console.WriteLine("{0}", accountBalance);
```

You can also use the various methods on `Convert` to be more forgiving, i.e.

```
decimal accountBalance = Convert.ToDecimal(dataReader["Balance"]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What a dumb rookie mistake :(. That works indeed - casting to decimal. Do you perhaps know why in debugging mode it shows "dataReader->Results View -> Empty"?

Comment: @AlicjaKrzeszowiec probably because that is iterating it as an enumerable, and you've already iterated to the end (the last row) by the time it fails? Note that you can only iterate a data-reader *once*